# How can I embed an Excel spreadsheet that allows users to edit certain fields, but is still "read-only"

Tags: embed

I have an Excel spreadsheet that I want to display on my blog.  The spreadsheet is a basically a moderately complex formula, with highlighting rules, that I want to allow the user to enter values into certain cells, and be able to see the "analysis" based upon their entries.

I don't want to save their entries (so if multiple people are viewing my blog, or they revisit the blog) they see the original values.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll have much success embedding an Excel spreadsheet on the web. I see two possible workarounds:

1. Make it into a Google Sheet document - then *that* can be embedded on your website or shared easily.
2. Make your Excel spreadsheet downloadable: your users will need their own copy of Excel (or emulator) to run it. the major downside here is that spreadsheets are known vectors for computer virus, so many people don't want to open them on their computer.

In both cases, you can tell your spreadsheet program to lock certain cells, so you would only leave unlocked the cells you want to allow users to modify.

Hope this helps!